# Can't ping from Win7 running on an MacBook Pro and Can't ping MacBook Pro from any other PC

Tags: windows, macos, networking, windows-7

I have Windows 7 Enterprise running on MacBook Pro and for some reason I'm not able to ping any PC in the house from it and the other way around meaning I can't ping the MacBook Pro running Win7 from any other PC.

I looked online but I can't find anything that explains this issue or how to resolve it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Please do let me know if I'm posting this in the wrong area.

Thank you

Comment: software used ?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on SuperUser.

Comment: @Ken, I used BootCamp if that's what you are asking for!!

Comment: @jorame under Virtualbox it's a matter of configuration about the virtual network card; probably this BootCamp software has the same features. Try look in the settings for your specific virtual machine.

Comment: This is not a software development question. I would recommend either SuperUser (as Casey Gregory suggested) or [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com) since there you shouldn't have to explain what Bootcamp is.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a firewall problem. I was having a similiar problem when connecting a Windows 7 PC with a MacOS device. I remember that turning of the firewall solved the problem. The firewall is not really necessary if you are behind a router...